# how to add amount when checkbox checked in grid view

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

**I have a `grid view` :**

in that i have a `checkbox` when i `check any of check box` it will `retrun` the `amount` , if i `click two or more checkbox it will return add both amount` when check false then return which is checked then return that amount..

**i tried:**

```
 //foreach (GridViewRow row in BillPayment.Rows)
        //{
        //    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("Chkbill");
        //    if (chk.Checked == true)
        //    {
        //        PaymentMode.Visible = true;
        //        ButSubmit.Visible = true;
        //        string s1 = BillPayment.Rows[0].Cells[3].Text;
        //        txtamtt.Text = s1;

        //    }
        //    if (chk.Checked == false)
        //    {
        //        txtamtt.Text = "";
        //    }
        //}
        //CheckBox chkTest = (CheckBox)sender;
        //GridViewRow grdRow = (GridViewRow)chkTest.NamingContainer;

        int count = 0;

        foreach (GridViewRow row in BillPayment.Rows)
        {
          //  CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("Chkbill");
            CheckBox chk = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("Chkbill") as CheckBox);
            if (chk.Checked==true)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }

        if (count >= 2)
        {
            //ddpayment.ClearSelection();
            //chqgrid();
            ////decimal s1;
            //PaymentMode.Visible = true;
            //ButSubmit.Visible = true;
            //con.Open();
            //string strng = "select partymaster.name as Party,sum(amount) Amount from Purchase_Master" +
            //             "\r\n inner join partymaster on partymaster.partyNo=Purchase_Master.partycode" +
            //             "\r\n where Purchase_Master.partycode ='"+ddvendor.SelectedValue+"' and verify=1 and paid=0" +
            //             "\r\n group by partymaster.name";
            //SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand(strng,con);
            //    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdd);
            //    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            //    da.Fill(dt);
            //    con.Close();
            //    if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
            //    {
            //        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            //        {
            //            txtamtt.Text=dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
            //        }
            //    }
            //else
            //{
            //    MessageInfo.MessageIcon = MessageIcons.ErrorIcon;
            //    TMessageBox1.Show(this.Title, "No Record Found", (TMessageBox.MessageIcons)MessageInfo.MessageIcon, true);
            //    return;
            //}
             if (count == 1)
        {

            ddpayment.ClearSelection();
            chqgrid();
            decimal s1;
            PaymentMode.Visible = true;
            ButSubmit.Visible = true;

            foreach (GridViewRow row in BillPayment.Rows)
            {
                //  CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("Chkbill");
                CheckBox chk = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("Chkbill") as CheckBox);
                if (chk.Checked == true)
                {
                    s1 = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[3].Text);
                    txtamtt.Text = s1.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        if (count == 0)
        {
            txtamtt.Text = "";
            PaymentMode.Visible = false;
            Chequegrid.Visible = false;
            ButSubmit.Visible = false;
        }
```

in **if(count>=2 )** i am having trouble,it will `not return` correct value,please help me.

Comment: in if(count>=2) there you have mistake right ,let me check,you have done the group by class ,in that situation you can do like that,it will return ,sum() all values,this will correct for 2 checkbox not more that 3,4 ,in that situation you have use for loop.

Comment: oh yes you say correctly ,but i try hard for that it will not return correctly.

Comment: ok wait , i will post answer

Answer (score 1):

if your (count==1) already return the correct amount, then you can make a slight change so it calculate all the ticked selection like this (note that i display the result in the textbox outside the loop after i finished the calculation

```
            ddpayment.ClearSelection();
            chqgrid();
            decimal s1,temp;
            PaymentMode.Visible = true;
            ButSubmit.Visible = true;
            temp=0;
            foreach (GridViewRow row in BillPayment.Rows)
            {
                //  CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("Chkbill");
                CheckBox chk = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("Chkbill") as CheckBox);
                if (chk.Checked == true)
                {
                    s1 = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[3].Text);
                    temp=temp+s1;
                }
            }
            txtamtt.Text = temp.ToString();
```

Comment: i will try that

Comment: i think that code can be used for any number of selection (not just 2), notice that the loop check all rows in the gridview. if nothing selected then the textbox will display 0 since its the initial value for temp variable

Comment: your answer is working in only one row check not both,